# Tensor fields on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, modules, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold. It is easily shown that the modules $\Gamma(TM)$ (the real vector space of vector fields on $M$) and $\Gamma(T^\ast M)$ (the real vector space of $1$-forms on $M$) are reflexive $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$-modules.

If the tangent bundle is parallelisable, then $\Gamma(TM)$ and $\Gamma(T^\ast M)$ are both free of rank $n$, so we can identify the linear maps out of $\Gamma(T^\ast M)^{\otimes p}\otimes\Gamma(TM)^{\otimes q}$ with elements of $\Gamma(TM)^{\otimes p}\otimes\Gamma(T^\ast M)^{\otimes q}$, and we always do this locally in a chart for $M$, even if the tangent bundle is not parallelisable.

Let's suppose that $M$ has a non-trivial tangent bundle, so that there is no basis of vector fields on $M$. What can we then say about $\Gamma(TM)$? It is clearly not free of rank $n$, so I don't think you can make the same identification as above, but it is "locally" free. Is there a name/description for a module like this?

Comment: What do you mean by a reflexive $C^{\infty}(M)$-module?

Comment: Well by definition, a reflexive $R$-module $M$ is a module such that the map $M\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(M^\ast,R)$, $m\to(\phi\to\phi(m))$ is a bijection, i.e. we can identify $M$ with its double dual. Is there any other thing this could mean?

Answer (score 1):

By the [Serre-Swan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem), at least if $M$ is closed, taking smooth sections defines an equivalence of categories between smooth vector bundles over $M$ and finitely generated projective modules over $C^{\infty}(M)$. This is more or less equivalent to the claim that every smooth vector bundle is a subbundle of a trivial vector bundle.

Comment: How about for general $M$? And does this mean that (if $M$ is closed) we can make the same identification as if $TM$ is trivial?